# sns.scatter plot python, specify size

Tags: python, size, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have the sns.scatterplot below, where I have set the size to Gap. The Gap values that have come up are 0, 0.8, 0.16 and 0.24, however the values in my dataframe are 0, 0.5, 1 and 2. How can I set them to equal the values in my dataframe?

`ax = sns.scatterplot(x='Number tapes', y='Ic', hue="Angle of twist (degree)", size="Gap", data=Ic_layers)`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values that are shown in the legend seem inconsistent with what you are saying the range of data is in your dataframe, but anyway...

You can use [`legend='full'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) in the call to `scatterplot()` to force seaborn to show a legend item for each of the levels of your hues/sizes variable.

```
N=50
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(size=(N,)), 'y': np.random.random(size=(N,)),
                   'size': np.random.choice([0, 0.5, 1, 2], size=(N,))})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", size="size", data=df, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('legend="brief" (default)')
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", size="size", data=df, legend='full', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('legend="full"')
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If that solution resolved your problem, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)